# Checking For Matching Email's In HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage where a user submits a form containing an email field and a confirm email field.

**How do I check to make sure both of these fields equal the same thing?**

```
<form>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br /><br />
Confirm Email: <input type="text" name="confirmemail"><br /><br /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This is tagged js and jquery, but shows none, and the form is sent to submit.PHP. Please clarify..

Comment: Updated tags, and the action for the form is irrelevant.

Comment: check where? server or client side? If you want it in client, shouldn't have removed the javascript tag

Comment: @user3130731 no it isn't irrelevant. It's submitted to php, so why not check in php?

Comment: Because the answer is within javascript/jquery, I know that for a fact. It has nothing to do with PHP. I want it client sided. I don't understand why people on this site are so concrete when it comes to the blatantly obvious.

Comment: Check with JavaScript (client side, optional) *before* submitting the form and validate server side (php presumably, but regardless this is *mandatory*) before submitting to a database. And if JavaScript is what you want to use there's no need to remove that tag, similarly for the jQuery tag if it's an acceptable option.

Comment: That's what I'm asking how to do David.

Comment: The 'answer' could be any range of things. Sure, you can use js/jquery, but you didn't provide any code or even address this in your question. You could also do this check in PHP, which you did mention in question (initially) but didn't tag. I was only trying to clarify..

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to use Javascript as you can stop form submission before it goes to your php file. However it is still good practice to verify the data entered with the php file as well as there are some programs that will allow you to change data being submitted in a form after javascript checks are made.

```
<script>
    function checkMatch() {
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var emailConfirm = document.getElementById('emailConfirm').value;

        if (email != emailConfirm) {
            alert("Email addresses are not the same.");
            return false; //Returning 'false' will cancel form submission
        } else {
            /*
            place the return true; at the end of the function if you do other
            checking and just have if conditions and return them as false. If
            one thing returns false the form submission is cancelled.
            */
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

And change your form to have `onSubmit`

```
<form method="post" action="submit_query.php" onSubmit="checkMatch()">
```

Add id's to your email inputs such as: email and emailConfirm. You can change them if you wish but just for an example I used those.

Comment: I have this: http://pastebin.com/pTB9tSww but my form still submits.. <form method="post" action="submit_query.php" onclick="checkMatch()">

Comment: I also have added ids.

Comment: `<form onSubmit="checkMatch()">` If it returns false the form will not submit. (added it to my answer)

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, but no error handling, I'd suggest:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
    return $('input[name=email]').val() == $('input[name=confirmemail]').val();
});
```

Ridiculously simple [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YXb93/).